How to use TypeScript with vue-i18n and arrays?
We created a simple landing page that displays countries defined in a Vue-i18n language.json file. This works fine but we get the following TypeScript errors:

[vue-tsc] Property 'code' does not exist on type 'never'.


[vue-tsc] Property 'name' does not exist on type 'never'.

It seems like the properties of a country are not found in the .json file. Although we did define the MessageSchema to be enUS, as described in the official documentation. For other strings in the lang.json files, there are no errors, only with a list or array it does not seem to default to String.
Please find a CodeSandBox for testing here. Below you can find the most important files.
File 'en-US.json'
 "page": {
    "landing": {
      "title": { "selectCountry": "Select your country" },
      "countries": [
        { "code": "BEL", "name": "Belgium" },
        { "code": "NLD", "name": "The Netherlands" }
      ]
    },

File '/boot/i18n.ts'
import enUS from 'src/i18n/en-US.json'
import nlBE from 'src/i18n/nl-BE.json'

export default boot(({ app }) => {
  // Type-define 'enUS' as the master schema for the resource
  type MessageSchema = typeof enUS

  const i18n = createI18n<[MessageSchema], 'en-US' | 'nl-BE'>({
    legacy: false,
    locale: Quasar.lang.getLocale(),
    fallbackLocale: 'en-US',
    messages: { 'en-US': enUS, 'nl-BE': nlBE },
  })

  app.use(i18n)
})

File 'LandingPage.vue'
<template>
  <q-page>
    <div>
      <q-card v-for="country in $tm('page.landing.countries')" :key="country.code">
        <q-card-section>
          <q-card-section>
            <div> {{ $rt(country.name) }} </div>
          </q-card-section>
        </q-card-section>
      </q-card>
    </div>
  </q-page>
</template>

Thank you for your help.

It's not known that the problem is specific to json. Does it exist with the usage that doesn't involve tm()? Did you try to specify messages directly instead of imported json?

I think Vue-i18n creates automatically a TS interface, but for arrays it doesn't seem to do this.

The template injections (e.g. $t, $tm) won't handle types correctly. So, the problem is not about using JSON. You would face the same issue even if you use .ts or .yaml files to store the i18n files.
You need to use the methods you want through useI18n() to get the proper types. Here is an example:
<template>
  <q-page>
    <div>
      <q-card v-for="country in tm('page.landing.countries')" :key="country.code">
        <q-card-section>
          <q-card-section>
            <div> {{ rt(country.name) }} </div>
          </q-card-section>
        </q-card-section>
      </q-card>
    </div>
  </q-page>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { useI18n } from 'vue-i18n';

const { tm, rt } = useI18n();
</script>

For this reason, when using TypeScript, I would recommend always using useI18n explicitly rather than using template injections. You will also see that you start getting autocompletion in i18n keys, e.g. t('will-get-autocomplete-here')

Thank you, I just tried it and we're still getting the errors Property 'code' does not exist on type 'number'. Does it work for you in the CodeSandBox?

As you said Yusuf, this is an issue reported on GitHub by Vue-i18n.
